# Search a binary tree in MIPS, really need assistance,

Tags: mips

I need to search a binary tree in MIPS for a term project. The code I have so. which he had a grad student type up so I don't know how good it is, far is :

```
text
   .globl __start
__start:

la $a0, tree
li $a1, 0
jal search

jal print_path

li $v0, 10
syscall



store_path:
mul $t0, $a1 4
sw $a0, path($t0)
addi $t0, $t0, 4
sw $a0, path($t0)
jr $ra


print_path:
li $t0, 0
mul $t1, $t0, 4
lw $a0, path($t1)   
next:   li $v0,4
    syscall
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #i++
mul $t1, $t0, 4
lw $a0, path($t1)
beqz $a0, done
move $t1, $a0
la $a0, arrow
li $v0, 4
syscall
move $a0, $t1
b next

done:   la $a0, endl
li $v0, 4
syscall
jr $ra


#---------------------------------------- code I need goes here. 
search: j store_path

 jr $ra



 #---------------------------------------- /code









.data

path: .space 40

tree:   .word name0, node1, node2, 0
node1:  .word name1, node3, node4, 0
node2:  .word name2, node5, node6, 0
node3:  .word name3, node7, 0, 0
node4:  .word name4, node8, node9, 0
node5:  .word name5, 0, 0, 0
node6:  .word name6, node10, node11, 0
node7:  .word name7, 0, 0, 0
node8:  .word name8, 0, 0, 0
node9:  .word name9, node12, node13, 0
node10: .word name10, 0, 0, 0
node11: .word name11, 0, 0, 0
node12: .word name12, node14, node15, 0
node13: .word name13, 0, 0, 0
node14: .word name14, 0, 0, 1
node15: .word name15, node16, node17, 0
node16: .word name16, 0, 0, 0
node17: .word name17, 0, 0, 0



name0: .asciiz "apple"
name1: .asciiz "orange"
name2: .asciiz "banana"
name3: .asciiz "pear"
name4: .asciiz "plum"
name5: .asciiz "peach"
name6: .asciiz "nectarine"
name7: .asciiz "pineapple"
name8: .asciiz "grapefruit"
name9: .asciiz "grape"
name10: .asciiz "melon"
name11: .asciiz "avacado"
name12: .asciiz "star"
name13: .asciiz "mange"
name14: .asciiz "passion"
name15: .asciiz "cantaloupe"
name16: .asciiz "watermelon"
name17: .asciiz "apricot"


endl: .asciiz "\n"
arrow: .asciiz "-->"
```

he gave us pseudo code to try and work from :

```
     call store_path
    if(value == 1)  //not sure what value is I'm guessing ether $a0 or $a1
     return 1   
    if(left tree exists)
     if(search(left tree, depth+1)
    return 1

   if(right tree exists)
   return search(right tree, depth +1)
   return 0
```

Hes never taught us how to do return or if statements. I know that jal and jr $ra work for return but not sure how exactly to return 1, or or return a search and only thing I've been able to do if statement like stuff with so far is break statements but last time that got marked wrong by him.  I asked him for help and he said look in the book, which I don't have because that costs about $800, it is out of print, when class started and I cannot afford that.

Could anyone help? I have no idea what I need to do, I suck at MIPS.

Comment: Even if you don't have that book you mention [it's not that hard](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse410/09sp/examples/MIPSCallingConventionsSummary.pdf) to find [the information you need](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) on the internet.